# Does Craft CMS have skeletons/starter/boilerplate templates?

Tags: templating

I'd like to set-up quickly blog on Craft CMS and I wonder if there are any starter templates available? It would be really useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m new to Craft and I’m surprised something bare bones like this doesn’t exist. At least I haven’t found anything yet. However, if I was to set out to create something like this I would use a stripped-down version of what is built in this awesome course at Mijingo. I’ve taken the course and it’s worth every penny.

https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/reusable-twig-templates-craft/

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how you can do it with Craft 3 and `composer create-project`: [nystudio107/craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft)

This is discussed in the [Setting up a New Craft CMS 3 Project](https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project) article.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you will find downloadable templates like for Wordpress and co because the philosophy of Craft is customization and the freedom to do what you want and not just downloading ready to use themes. Since everyone can build his/her completely own structure it's literally useless to create downloadable templates. You should try to build your own: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview

There are example templates which contain enough code to get you started in the templates folder `craft/templates` or [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/whats-the-right-way-to-create-a-simple-blog-in-craft) as well.

If you don't want to have the freedom to customize everything you should search for another CMS.

Comment: I'm not asking for theme, i'm asking for boilerplate.
I know philosophy of Craft about templating, however blog structure is something that can't be done in 1000 different ways. Having barebones starter with post list, post, pages, archives, author, tag pages would make life much simpler!

Answer (score 5):

You can try this one:
[Instablog](https://github.com/70kft/craft-instablog)
It could be a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on starter/boilerplate theme for Craft CMS 3:

http://craftsnippets.com/starter-theme-for-craft-cms?s=s

This theme contains:

- Base Twig template structure and multiple useful snippets
- Base CSS code (kinda opinionated)
- Gulp config for compiling static assets and handling browsersync