# Blog template not displaying posts

Tags: craft3, error-templates

The blog post should display the posts created but when I got to the slug /blog it says 404 not found as well as the press news should be displayed here /press-news but same thing happens.

If i access the posts directly : site.com/blog/blog-post-name it is displayed correctly.

an you help me giving me some probable causes so that i can check how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you've setup a channel, it does not include a "blog index" by default, for this you need to make it yourself by placing an index.twig file within the blog folder (If that is a directory in your templates folder).

Check the answer in this question for an example on how to do the twig code.
[What's the right way to create a simple blog in Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/whats-the-right-way-to-create-a-simple-blog-in-craft)

Comment: Thanks 2 for providing this info. im gonna try the twig code.

Comment: that index.twig file, what should i include? what will be the content to put on it? thanks for the response.

Comment: thanks for your help, indeed it was very informative.

Answer (score 2):

If `blog` is a channel and `site.com/blog/blog-post-name` is correctly displayed but you can't access `site.com/blog`, that is probably because you are missing an `index.html` template inside the `blog` folder.

Craft will do the route automatically if you add an index.html file inside a section folder. (rightly named)

Then, what you want is to display the blog related posts inside that template.
From there, just make a simple Craft request and loop through the result.

Something like that should work:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').all %}
    <article>
        <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

I invite you to read the [official doc](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html), all the basics (like that one) are well documented and a lot of examples are available.

You may also take a look at the [Routing documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html) to understand the step behind Craft routing.